# Limited to a single user logging into a website - share browser so multiple users can login

Tags: browser, sharing

Myself and a friend have a single user id to login to a website.  I can login to the site but he has to wait until I log out to use the site on the same login id.  Ive seen lots of screen sharing apps, looked at lots of ideas but technically it can be done im sure.

I want to login on my pc, he wants to access the site from a differnt pc.

Whats the easiest way to do this? I am using thinking about using opencoweb and iframes to simply share the session browser state and information.  Is it possible?

Should I be able to do this with deploying an iframed page on app server?

Comment: Ask on superuser not here this is a programming Q&A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No proxy needed. Simply copy the cookie file, import it via the other browser and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

buy another subscription to that service - or put a proxy on your computer and tell your friend to connect to that site through your proxy

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you both should connect to the site from a single proxy server, so your ip will be the same. After one of you login into his account, the other should copy this site cookies to his computer. The site will check cookie and ip, it will be unable to distinguish between you.

Comment: ok, so I have a single IP, using firefox would it be that simple simply copy the cookie for the site accessed?

Comment: Yes if your friend have the same IP as yours. Of course, there are some tricky ways to detect this behaviour, it depends on site.

Comment: its a sqlite database in firefox right so cookie copying is only going to be a full sqlite db copy...

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookies-exportimport/ copy the cookie details (import just the site we need) and it seems to allow us to both login at the same time!!!